# How do I add a back button to a navbar in a uiviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uistoryboardsegue

I have an app with a uitabbarcontroller with 2 tabs.

The first tab is a mapview in a uiviewcontroller with pins that i need to call a detail tableview controller.

The second is a tableviewcontroller with a list of the same locations as before that I need to call the same detail tableview controller.

Ive added the detailVC to storyboards and added a navbar to it.  how do I add a back button to that navbar that will return to the calling vc (mapview or listvc)?

I would add a segue from both the pin (pinToDetailVC segue identifier) and the list cell (cellToDetailVC), so I could add unwind segues to return to the proper vc.  But I cant seem to add the back button to the navbar.

Here is what it looks like...[image: a mapview and tableview calling on the same detailVC]

Answer (score 1):

You want to embed the 2 view controllers into a `UINavigationController`, then the second view controller is pushed into the navigation controller. Then you don't need to explicitly add the back button as it will automatically be added for you. You also wouldn't need to add the `unwind segues`.

Comment: I added the picture of what my storyboard looks like.  I cant have 2 different VCs (map & tableview) embedding the same VC (detailVC), can I?

Comment: Sure you can. The detailVC is just a class definition. You can instantiated it as many times as you need and use each instance as you want. You can have multiple segues linking to the same controller.